# High cpu usage by region server role on one datanode after upgrade from CDH 5.5.1 to 5.7.2

Tags: cloudera-cdh

After upgrading from CDH 5.5.1 to 5.7.2, I am facing high cpu usage by one of region server role on one datanode in cluster. And overall performance of Hbase is also downgraded. Please suggest any check or fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a lot of writes occurring when you took it offline?  This will require replaying the write ahead log entries.

Does this region server have the meta region?  It could be that you have a cache issue where you are repeatedly looking up meta instead of using the Cache on the Connection.

Comment: At Splice Machine (Open Source), we have adapters for all the different HBase versions to run a relational database on top of HBase.  There are nuances with each one, especially around connection factories and caches.

Comment: Thanks for replying! How can i check that lot of writes occurring on that datanode?

Comment: we have total 6 datanodes in cluster and datanode03 have this issue. I have checked hdfs for meta file under /hbase/WALs/datanode03.xxx.com,60020,1472090618537, but no meta file exist. There is one more path /hbase/WALs/datanode03.xxx.com,60020,1439199339222-splitting, which have meta file (datanode03.xxx.com%2C60020%2C1439199339222..meta.1441175802751.meta). But this meta file is not updated for last 1 year.

Comment: Given that you are using CDH, I am assuming that you have Cloudera Manager.  You can look at regionserver read and write requests with Cloudera Managers Charting capabilities.  if you got to the Chart Builder you can build charts that query regionserver stats like read and write requests with statements like: `select read_requests_rate where serviceName=hbase` or `select write_requests_rate where serviceName=hbase` look here for more details: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_metrics.html

Comment: Hi, I have build charts to monitor read and write request rate. As per the graph statistics, earlier lots of write were occurring on datanode03. then we have bounced the cluster service for some maintenance and after that lots of write were occurring on datanode06. Now I can say that lots of writes are the reason of high cpu consumption. Overall performance of hbase is not good as some of the daily jobs are taking double time to complete as compared to the time before upgrade. What should I do now to fix the performance issue in hbase cluster?